# Largest integer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

It's kinda hard to believe -- but I can't find info about the largest possible integer allowed in node.js, in either Google or SO. There are plenty of articles on the largest integer in browser Javascript, but I just wonder things could be different in node.js.

Can anyone give some pointer? Thanks!

Comment: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` - just like all javascript engines

Comment: Define "largest integer."

Comment: Try running `console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)`. 
NodeJS is fancy, but at its heart it's still just JavaScript.

Comment: You can find the response right there : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Thanks guys for the useful info!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> There are plenty of articles on the largest integer in browser Javascript, but I just wonder things could be different in node.js.

No. JavaScript is JavaScript, a language defined [by specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html). So the answers you find for "browser JavaScript" also apply to NodeJS.

The maximum integer value that can be represented by a IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point number (the kind JavaScript uses) is 1.7976931348623157 x 10<sup>308</sup>, which is available in JavaScript as `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

The maximum integer that you can reliably add 1 to and not get the same value back due to a loss of precision is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is 9,007,199,254,740,991. That is, `9007199254740991 + 1` is `9007199254740992`, but `9007199254740992 + 1` is also `9007199254740992`. There are much larger integers that can be held (see above), but the gaps between them grow as the value increases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "JavaScript is JavaScript". The rest all makes sense.